# Difference of return or throw in recursive algorithm in javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion

Hi I am a beginner trying to learn recursion. I am trying to write a function about combinatorial algorithm in the ArrayAdditionI(arr)  if arr contains [4, 6, 23, 10, 1, 3] the output should return true because 4 + 6 + 10 + 3 = 23. 23 is the maximum number in the array. if none combination gives 23, the function returns false.

In my code I tried to use return but didn't work, then I change it to throw it works.
I understand why throw works but am confused why return did not work.

Here is my code in js that is working:

```
function ArrayAdditionI(arr) { 

//remove the maximal number from arr

var m = arr[0];
for (var i=0; i<arr.length-1;i++)
m =  Number(arr[i]) > Number(arr[i+1]) ? arr[i]:arr[i+1];
arr.splice(arr.indexOf(m),arr.indexOf(m));

//Here the recursion starts:

var combiAdd = function (a){
  var sum = 0;   
  for (var j=0; j<a.length;j++){
    sum += a[j];
    if (sum == m)
      throw true;
    else if (sum != m && j==a.length-1){
      if (a.length == 1)
        throw false;//switch to the "return false;"
      else
        combiAdd(a.splice(1,a.length));//switch to "return combiAdd(a.splice(1,a.length));
    }
  }        
}    

try {
    combiAdd(arr);
  }
catch(exp){
if (exp !=true && exp!=false)
  throw exp;
else 
  return exp;}
}
```

Here is my code with return that's not working:

```
//...same code as above
    if (a.length == 1) //same code
      return false;
    else
      return combiAdd(a.splice(1,a.length));
```

It gives me undefined message for a supposedly false array like [4, 7, 10, 1]

Can anyone help me? Thank you!

Comment: You did have `return combiAdd(a.splice(1,a.length));` in your actual code, and not just `combiAdd(a.splice(1,a.length));`, right? The most likely error seems to be that you forgot to put `return`, but then when you were writing your StackOverflow post, you remembered to return the value.

Comment: You probably want `arr.splice(arr.indexOf(m),1);` instead of `arr.splice(arr.indexOf(m),arr.indexOf(m));`. The second argument is an element count, not an element index.

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify your code.

```
function ArrayAdditionI(arr) {
    var sum = 0, max;

    // remove the biggest number
    // and put the max number in a variable
    max = arr.splice( arr.indexOf( Math.max.apply(null, arr) ), 1)[0];

    // add the remaining numbers
    sum = arr.reduce(function (a, b) { return a + b; });

    return sum === max;
}
```

Comment: I realize that, but what he was doing is much too complicated. There are better ways to learn recursion.